# Oauth implementation for graphql in Magento2

Tags: magento, oauth, graphql, adobe, magento2

I have to implement OAuth for graphql API in Magento, I went through the documentation of Magento but I found that only we can authenticate by using username and password

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/authorization-tokens.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/generate-customer-token.html

We are creating a PWA application and web application is going to use it directly

Is there any other way to authenticate means any other authentication layer

Answer (score 0):

Including this below to this very old question, if in case some others coming across this question.

- Magento Graphql in the core implemented currently to handle more of frontend user request which will be in the form of either asking for some data that's either only to read or submit personal data (such as placing order with address)
- There are modules available with the support of Graphql to handle E2E ERP sync (products & order fulfillment) , OOTB does not support everything that you might able to do with the use of oAuth Integration token + REST API.

You would want to determine the actual outcome or scope to decide on the authentication / authorization mode and then decide on the API layer medium. If in case of Integration token based approach is what decided for data / access security reasons then REST API will be easier option for the most of the OOTB functionalities.